# Is this the correct way to set a CSS gradient with two color stops?

Tags: css, less

I have been trying for some time to make my code work with all the browser prefixes below. This is what I have come up with. Can someone tell me if this is the correct way to code the gradient using Less? In particular I'm confused about -webkit-linear-gradient as I can't find how to do this with the spec.

My less code:

```
.setTopGradient(@startClr, @endClr, @st1Clr, @st1Pos, @st2Clr, @st2Pos) {
   @st1PosPercent: @st1Pos * 100%;
   @st2PosPercent: @st2Pos * 100%;

   background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        @startClr,
        @st1Clr @st1PosPercent,
        @st2Clr @st2PosPercent,
        @endClr
   );

   background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, 
        left @startClr,
        left @endClr, 
        color-stop(@st1Pos, @st1Clr),
        color-stop(@st2Pos, @st2Clr)
   );

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      from(@startClr),
      to(@endClr),
      color-stop(@st1Pos, @st1Clr),
      color-stop(@st2Pos, @st2Clr)
   );

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(
        @startClr 0%,
        @st1Clr @st1PosPercent,
        @st2Clr @st2PosPercent,
        @endClr 100%
    );

    background: -o-linear-gradient(
        @startClr 0%,
        @st1Clr @st1PosPercent,
        @st2Clr @st2PosPercent,
        @endClr 100%
    );

    background: linear-gradient(
        to @endClr,
        @st1Clr @st1PosPercent,
        @st2Clr @st2PosPercent,
        @endClr 100%
    );

}
```

Sample Input:

```
.setTopGradient(#8b8b8b,#bfbfbf,#a9a9a9,0.1,#bdbdbd,0.3);
```

Output CSS:

```
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8b8b8b, #a9a9a9 10%, #bdbdbd 30%, #bfbfbf);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left #8b8b8b, left #bfbfbf, color-stop(0.1, #a9a9a9), color-stop(0.3, #bdbdbd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8b8b8b), to(#bfbfbf), color-stop(0.1, #a9a9a9), color-stop(0.3, #bdbdbd));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#8b8b8b 0%, #a9a9a9 10%, #bdbdbd 30%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#8b8b8b 0%, #a9a9a9 10%, #bdbdbd 30%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to #bfbfbf, #a9a9a9 10%, #bdbdbd 30%, #bfbfbf 100%);
```

Comment: `with different browsers` Like?

Comment: Try online css gradient generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ or http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Comment: What's the reason to use LESS, if you still write any vendor-prefixes manually? Also you can't find the old Webkit format in the W3C specification, because it wasn't used in the CSS specification – this was a working draft for Webkit.

Comment: see line 410: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less

Comment: @feeela - Can you explain what you mean. Are you saying that I should not need to bother about including the -webkit-linear-gradient as it was not really used. Thanks very much.

Comment: @feeela - it's a mixin - you need to specify it first in order to use it as shortcut later on in code. Code will still be output as vendor prefixed.

Comment: @Scott - when I look at the link you gave me I see that they are all using percentages. Can you confirm then my coding for webkit-gradient is wrong. I got this from another user here who suggested using non-percentages for this.

Comment: @easwee Then I don't get the whole idea behind LESS and how it could save me some work. I thought LESS would create such vendor prefixed properties by default and a developer only need to type one variant.

Comment: @feeela If you use a less based framework (like bootstrap or http://lesselements.com) this is all created for you just to use - otherwise LESS is just a tool that adds extra options to css - you still have to write your functions yourself. It's totally useless for simple projects - but saves a lot of work once you have complex dynamic layouts and minimal control over html structure.

Comment: @Anne: If the essence of this question revolves around the use of percentages, then check out the revised answer to your previous question. In my original answer, I used decimals simply because you did (without thinking about it or researching it further), but percentages are used in `webkit`.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to this question, make your stops just percentages (no decimals), so that these lines...

```
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left #8b8b8b, left #bfbfbf, color-stop(0.1, #a9a9a9), color-stop(0.3, #bdbdbd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8b8b8b), to(#bfbfbf), color-stop(0.1, #a9a9a9), color-stop(0.3, #bdbdbd))
```

...become...

```
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left #8b8b8b, left #bfbfbf, color-stop(10%, #a9a9a9), color-stop(30%, #bdbdbd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8b8b8b), to(#bfbfbf), color-stop(10%, #a9a9a9), color-stop(30%, #bdbdbd))
```